# is it possible to replace images in an array dynamically

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone.what i am need is to place a 20 images names in an array . if i place those images in an array whether it is possible or not to change replace the first image by last means changing the positions of images dynamically if it is not possible pls suggest in what way i can done this. pls post any sample code  thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NSMutableArray. It has methods like

```
- (void)replaceObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index withObject:(id)anObject;


- (void)exchangeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx1 withObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx2;
```

It does not matter whether your objects are strings or images or whatever. It is possible to change the objects in a mutable array.